# How to Find Number of Pets Each Person Has

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, aggregate

I'm learning MySQL and was having a hard time making a query to find the number of pets each person has. Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE person(
person_id integer primary key auto_increment,
person_name varchar(500) NOT NULL,
person_birthdate date not null
);

CREATE TABLE pet(
pet_id integer primary key auto_increment,
person_id integer not null,
pet_name varchar(500) not null,
pet_type varchar(500) not null,
Foreign key (person_id) references person (person_id),
Index (person_id)
);
```

Comment: it is conventional here for you to provide an attempted query even if  it has errors, then ask for help on that query.  It is useful to us to see the tables (thanks) but best practice is to provide "sample data" and your "expected result" from that sample.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

```
Select person_id,count(person_id) as totalPets from pet group by person_id
```

Here is your desired query.

Comment: This query will only find those persons who do have pets, but there could be persons with zero pets. The question asks to "find the number of pets **each person** has" which includes those with no pets.

Comment: Then you've to select the person table first and left join it with the pet table, then count it by after grouping.

Comment: Yes, I do know that, but I doubt the person who asked the question does.

Answer (score 1):

For a new answer, join the two tables, group by the person, and the count of entries is the number a person has:

```
select person_name, count(*) as NumPets
from person p
left join pet pt
  on pt.person_id = p.person_id
group by p.person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of pets is a simple count, correlated on the `person_id`, such as:

```
select person_name, 
  coalesce((select count(*) from pet pt where pt.person_id = p.person_id),0) NumPets
from person p;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a case in a left join query to include people who do not own a pet.

```
insert into person values(1,'john',19991010),(2,'marry',20000101),(3,'terry',19981101);
insert into pet values(1,2,'doggy','dog'),(2,3,'catty','cat'),(3,2,'snaky','snake');

select ps.person_id ,case when count(pet_id) is null then 0 else count(pet_id) end as pet_count 
from person ps 
left join pet pt on ps.person_id=pt.person_id 
group by ps.person_id;
```

The result set is as expected:

person_id, pet_count

'1', '0'

'2', '2'

'3', '1'